# ImportError: No module named rest_framework_jwt.views

Tags: django, python-2.7, ubuntu

I am using Ubuntu and Django (Python 2.7.12)

I am trying to run `python manage.py migrate` but an error shows up:

```
from rest_framework_jwt.views import obtain_jwt_token
ImportError: No module named rest_framework_jwt.views
```

I have already installed rest like this:

```
pip install djangorestframework
```

Any idea about the error?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

JWT is a [separate package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/djangorestframework-jwt/), so you need to install it via `pip install djangorestframework-jwt`.

Note, depending on the version(s) of Python you have installed, you *might* need to use `pip3` instead of `pip` if you are trying to use this/install it for Python 3.

See the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42512171/importerror-no-module-named-rest-framework-jwt-views/57369810#57369810) regarding Simple JWT, which replaced JWT in 2019.

Answer (score 5):

Be aware that JWT has [not been maintained since ~2019](https://github.com/jpadilla/django-rest-framework-jwt/issues/484). There is a newer project, [Simple JWT](https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), that you may use instead, if you need newer features. You can install it with this command:

```
pip install djangorestframework-simplejwt
```

Answer (score 0):

django-restgramework-jwt is deprecated in new version.
so kindly follows,
pip install djangorestframework-simplejwt

Answer (score 0):

Try use:

```
pip install drf-jwt
```

or

```
pip3 install drf-jwt
```